# Can I combine error exception and a conditional in a single line?

Tags: python, error-handling, conditional-statements

If for example, my code does something like this:

```py
try:
    for n in graph[x]:
        #...
        #...
        if event == 0:
            #do something
except IndexError:
        #do the same thing
```

My `if` block and my error exception block have the same exact code; so instead of having redundant lines, I want to combine the two blocks. I want to do something like `except IndexError or if target == 0:` as a single conditional. Is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: You could write a function and call it in both places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest, though a bit hacky: change your

```
    if event == 0:
        #do something
```

to

```
    if event == 0:
        raise IndexError
```

so as to "tickle" the following `except IndexError` clause.

Cleaner is to turn the `do something` into an inner function `def`d just before the whole `try` statement; but it does take a wee little bit more work in some cases.

Comment: What you say is true. But suppose it is then is safe to presume that python does not proffer a way to combine conditionals and exceptions into a single expression.

Comment: @Eyeofpie, yep -- in Python like in Java or C++, catching exceptions is one thing, conditionals another -- you merge two such cases in the either of the ways I've shown above for Python, in each of the languages.